# How to make work UIDocumentInteractionController in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, delegates, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, uidocumentinteraction

I am trying to open a *.epub file throught my application and I don't quite understand how to make it with the UIDocumentInteractionController class. I have seen the official IOS [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [examples](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html) and some of the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) over [the net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910787/strange-problem-with-uidocumentinteractioncontroller) but I don't understand how that class works. This is how I do it, what I achieve and what I dont understand:

I have a UIView with a UIButton:

```
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System.Drawing;

public class MyView : UIViewController
{
    UIButton myBtn;

    public MyView() :base()
    {
        View.Frame = new RectangleF(0,0,1024,768);

        var myRect = new RectangleF(300,300,100,50);

        myBtn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        myBtn.Frame = myRect;
        myBtn.TouchUpInside += delegate
        {
            var dic = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(new NSUrl("http://192.168.50.50:2020/myfile.epub"));
            var dicDel = new UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate();
            dic.Delegate = dicDel;

            InvokeOnMainThread(delegate
            {
                var result = dic.PresentOpenInMenu(myRect, View, true);
                //If I do this -> NullReferenceException because delegate is null (something about autorelease?? Don't know)
                if(!result) dic.Delegate.DidDismissOpenInMenu(dic);
            });


        }
    }
}
```

The weirdest thing is if I debug and inspect "dic" (without the delegate) before calling the PresentOpenInMenu() method it shows the menu (returning true) but just after doing it the app blows up on Main.cs because the autorelease thing I dont understand.

I am a little lost. Can someone help me understand this class and how can I make it work correctly? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: By the way, I used a *.txt file too with same results.

Comment: I just tried your example and the error I get is:
 UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme http.  Only the file scheme is supported.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a MonoTouch bug. Setting the `UIDocumentInteractionController.Delegate` (or `WeakDelegate` property and then querying its value returns **null** (which will fail later on).

I'll look into this bug and update this answer if I can provide a workaround (until the bug is properly fixed in a future release of MonoTouch).

**UPDATE**: `UIDocumentInteractionController` already creates it's own internal `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` so you do not need to create one. The Delegate methods, like `DidDismissOpenInMenu` are available as events on `UIDocumentInteractionController` itself.

Remove your own Delegate (creation and set) and use the events and you should be fine.

**UPDATE #2**: The `Delegate` property returns null since the default `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` is not usable as is. It is meant to be inherited from and customized to do what you want to (and the *unusable* default one is not registred properly to be used). E.g.

```
class MyDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate : UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate { }
```

and

```
var dicDel = new MyDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate ();
```

would *work*, as in no `NullReferenceException`, but of course `DidDismissOpenInMenu` won't be doing anything interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer poupou, I already solved the issue. Indeed the delegate is not instanced and if you want to handle its events on your own you need to create a class inheriting the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate class and overriding those methods, but if you only want to show the options/preview/openIn menu you don't need the delegate at all.

Comment: Ok I was looking for my code but I don't have here now, so I will post it tomorrow, promise.

The key thing was I was missing how to retain the object after calling it, I needed to make the declaration of the DocumentInteractionController as a property and put it the 

[Export ("PresentOptionsMenu", MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.ArgumentSemantic.Retain)] attribute

Comment: Providing a xxxDelegate is **optional** and allows you to customize the main class (`UIDocumentInteractionController` in this case). This is always supported in MonoTouch - but the base xxxDelegate class wont help since it's not doing anything (until you inherit from it). Some types, including `UIDocumentInteractionController` also **optionally** *hides* the xxxDelegate (it uses an internal one) and let you customize using C# events (which are more .NET friendly).