# UIDocumentInteractionController will fail to open document in Ibook

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ibooks, uidocumentinteraction

Th problem is that  "success" is always return me false? I do not what is the problem?

my code as follows:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:currentPDFPath] retain];

if (docController)
{
    docController.delegate = self;

    BOOL success = [docController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:openInButton animated:YES]; 
    //BOOL success = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:openInButton animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"success: %d", success);
    if(!success)
    {
        UIAlertView * noApps = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your iPad doesn't seem to have any other Apps installed that can open this document (such as iBooks)" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [noApps show];
        [noApps release];

    }
}
    [docController release];
```

Comment: what does currentPDFPath contain?

Comment: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/14DD059B-9969-4960-8E24-DC586A4302D1/Library/Caches/http-__wgsn.howoco.com_media_event_117_AW12_13_Tradeshow_seasonal_analysis_-_colour_1340296472.pdf%3F1340297029

Comment: @PriyankaChhetri Did u find a solution for this, please let me know, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The [class reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDocumentInteractionController/presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:) says:

> **Return Value**
>
> `YES` if the options menu was displayed or `NO` if it was not. The options menu may not be displayed in cases where there are no appropriate items to include in the menu.

I think your `%3F1340297029` suffix on `currentPDFPath` may be preventing a [UTI](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1) match.

Check the `UTI` property of `docController` and set to [`kUTTypePDF`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kUTTypePDF) if it is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for replying.My this problem is resolved. Now "BOOL success" is returning 1. But I am not able to open this pdf in iBook.

Comment: Now the error is "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible."

Answer (score 0):

Your crashing issue is probably because your docController has already been released. You'll need to retain it and then autorelease it later. Have a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3474825/523350

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit, not it is working for me, I am using ARC, so you have to change it to fit your non-ARC code.

```
BOOL success = [self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];

                if (success == NO) {
                    NSLog(@"No application was found");
                } else {

                    NSLog(@"Applications were found");
                }
```

The `BOOL` is either returning `YES` or `NO`, `YES` it the line behind the `=` is `TRUE` and `NO` if the line is `FALSE`.

--David